# Have Google Home trigger smart device

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, home-automation, amazon-echo

I'm developing a smart device that needs to respond to a trigger and take an action.  I'm having some trouble however determining what will host the code that fires the trigger.  Google Home appears to have events based on time but I can't seem to find anything that can trigger an event based on something like the weather.  IFTTT seems like a natural fit but to have customers install IFTTT and then find my applet is a bit cumbersome.  I could have my server monitor the condition and fire the trigger but ideally the trigger could be generated on-prem.

So my question... Does anyone have a good suggestion for where to host code that fires a trigger that is sent to a smart device?

*first-time poster so forgive me for any lack of formalities

Comment: Can you share a bit more information about the type of event trigger you're looking to have your device respond to?

Comment: The trigger would be a weather based event, such as rain.

Answer (score 0):

Automations on Google Home are available for triggering actions but might cover all the use cases you specified. You can create your own system that changes the states of the devices based on your conditions, then report to Google via Report State.